# Can't use specific numbers within a range

Tags: ios, swift

I've come across a strange bug in my code where I am unable to use specific numbers within a range that are from another range of numbers. To be precise the range (1..<1000) in the function `validateValueS` does not allow numbers 2 through 50, I can only speculate why this may be happening do to there being another function that contains a range of numbers between 2 through 50. But I'm not sure how this is effecting my said range.

The expected result is for both text fields to accept numbers with in the desired ranges. The actual result is only one text field is accepting all of the numbers within its range.

Comment: Can we see the output of you trying to enter a number between 2-50? Or better yet, could we see a list of results when you try to do 48-52? It would give proof, not that we don’t believe you, but would help :)

Comment: can you show the error log that happens in the video?

Comment: I would highly recommend running on both simulator and actual device and see if you get the same results. Especially with errors that crash into the AppDelegate. Let me know!

Comment: @aiwiguna https://imgur.com/5uD8zYI

Answer (score 0):

from your video here https://imgur.com/5uD8zYI

the error is there is no segue with identifier 'server'

please check your segue identifier in the storyboard

example [image]

in this example

1. you have 'Server' segue in the playerVC
2. your current VC is the serverVC
3. if you call 'Server' segue in the serverVC it will be crash because serverVC only have 'Next' segue

Comment: Well trust me there is. I just checked.

Comment: can you show the storyboard? it may there is the 'server' segue but in the different VC because the segue is depends on the VC, you cannot access segue that not connected with the current VC even if it have the same identifier

Comment: Also, if you deleted a segue or changed it - click on each ViewController in the storyboard and be sure to remove original segues if you added ones or changedd them

Comment: In your example that is how mine is set up.

Comment: If your storyboard same with the example, you call wrong segue like yg explained in the post